# Regular Expression Not characters

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression that does not allow characters.

```
^[A-Z0-9 _]*[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9 _]*$
```

These doesn't seem to work, as I need to escape any type of character (English, Chinese, Greek, etc.)

Comment: `\W` would be the negation of `\w`.

Comment: Are you looking for RegExp not allowing characters or strings? Should that RegExp match all inputs *not matched* by `^[A-Z0-9 _]*[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9 _]*$`?

Comment: What do you mean by escaping any type of characters? Do you mean escaped characters should be matched as well?

Comment: Which regex motor are you using? Java, .Net, perl?

Comment: I use php if you mean that. I just want a RegExp that contains only numbers and dots(.). I just want  not to allow characters. For example 5.1.22 is valid. 2.2.14εζ or 2.21.p is not valid

Comment: Normally the term 'character' refers to any text element, including digits, punctuation, etc. So '1' is a character. '!' is a character. Do you mean that you want to not allow _letters_, characters that are part of an alphabet?

Comment: Just use the reverse logic: try and match one character in the input, if you succeed, the input is invalid

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to accept digits and the . character using POSIX (PHP):

```
^[.1-9]*$
```

---

If you want to explicit exclude word characters

```
^[^\w]*$
```

This will match anything but [word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#WordCharacter) characters.

Note (that as has been replied in the comments):

- this will work with JGsoft, .NET, Perl, Python.
- It will *not* work if using Java, JavaScript, PCRE, Ruby, POSIX.

You edited your post and stated that you use PHP. As far as I know it uses POSIX ERE. In that case this solution will *not* work. However I keep my answer for the search functionality in case another user (that does use the supported engines) finds this answer.

Comment: That depends highly upon the regex motor you use. In Java for instance \w is equivalent of [a-zA-Z_0-9].

Comment: @Bergi I was unsure whether he wanted to exclude more characters. This way the can be added. However if that is not the case, \W should be ok. Thank you!

Comment: @AleksanderBlomskøld Good argument. I confirmed that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\p{L}` or `\p{Letter}` to match any (Unicode) letter in any language. To match any non-letter you should negate by using either: `\p{^L}` or `\P{L}` (depending upon the regex engine you're using).

Answer (score 0):

Any character   \w
Not a charater  \W

Comment: This only works for ascii characters in most regex implementations. For instance: \w doesn't match 'ø' in Java.